# This program will compile but not run. Other programs run

Tags: c++

So, I'm using dev-C++. The compiler works fine, a simple hello world program works along with about a dozen other simple programs. This is a work-in-progress of something I'm working on for class.

For me this compiles but it never runs. What's wrong with it?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

void getNames(vector<string> &vectorName, int &last, string temp);

int main() {
    vector<string> names;
    string tmp;
    int last = 0;

    getNames(names, last, tmp);

    for(int j = 0; j < last; j++) {
        cout << names.at(j) << endl;
    }

    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void getNames(vector<string> vectorName, int &last, string temp) {

    while (true) {
        cout << "Enter a name (quit to stop): ";
        cin >> temp;
    if (temp == "quit") break;
        vectorName.push_back(temp);
        last = vectorName.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: define "never runs". What if you run it manually? Do you see any errors? If so, what are they?

Comment: First thing I see is that `getNames` definition has a different parameter than what you declared (missing a `&`)

Comment: place a breakpoint on `getNames` in your `main` function and see if it gets there.  If it does, press F10 until it stops working and let us know where it stops working

Answer (score 4):

The program should fail to link because it can't find the definition for:

```
void getNames(vector<string> &vectorName, int &last, string temp);
```

That's because you're missing the `&` in your definition:

```
void getNames(vector<string> vectorName, int &last, string temp){
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Add in the `&` and it should compile and run just fine.

Comment: @Brayheim: Why do you use a forward-declaration anyway? Just shuffle the functions around.

Comment: @Deduplicator Yeah, it's for class and my prof is weird about function prototypes.

Comment: @Brayheim: Well, that's probably good training for work, if you get a bad chef who insists on bad coding standards.

Answer (score 1):

First your `getNames` declaration and implementation signatures are not exactly the same.

```
void getNames(vector<string> &vectorName, int &last, string temp){
void getNames(vector<string> vectorName, int &last, string temp){
```

Comment: Nevermind that was a mistake from me, thought he was using C strings and not C++ strings.